# Sort multiple csv files (in one directory) by their individual columns

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I am very new to python coding so any advice would help! I have to create a function that will take all csv files in one directory and sort it by their individual columns.  Each csv file must be sorted by the first column (date) and then the second column (time) and then the third column (activity).

The code I have sorts the data but it merges all the files together.  How can I keep the files separate of each other?

```
import glob
data=[]
path="/Users/sara/Desktop/*.csv"
files=glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    f=open(file, "r")
    for line in f:
        data.append(line)
data=sorted(data, key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1],x[2]))
print(sorted(data))
```

Comment: please post your code as text, otherwise I cannot be read by search engines and copied by other users

Comment: You are appending each line of each file to the same list, so I'd expect it to sort all lines of all files, but what do you want it to do differently?

Comment: i would like the files to stay within themselves respectively.  so i would like to append each line of each file to their own lists.  Therefore, if i had three files in the directory, I would end up with three sorted lists

Comment: @classact, I suggest you use a dict to store those three lists. Refer to my answer for the detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so you seem to be appending the info in every file to the same list, I would suggest doing a list of list's like this

```
import glob
data=[]
path="/Users/sara/Desktop/*.csv"
files=glob.glob(path)
sorted_files = []
for file in files:
    f=open(file, "r")
    for line in f:
        data.append(line)

    data=sorted(data, key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1],x[2]))
    sorted_files.append(data)

for sorted_file in sorted_files:
    print(sorted(sorted_file))
```

So every time a file is completely read it and sorted it appends that list to the list `sorted_files` so to print out each file individually sorted you could access like this, `sorted_files[0]` this would give you the first sorted file

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict to store your sorted lists,

```
import csv
import operator
import glob

data = dict() # filename : lists

path="/Users/sara/Desktop/*.csv"
files=glob.glob(path)

for filename in files:
    # process each file
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # read file to a list of lists
        lists = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')]
        # sort and save into a dict
        data[filename] = sorted(lists, operator.itemgetter(0, 1, 2))
```

And now you can get the sorted lists for a given filename,

```
lists = data[filename]
```